# Is $a^2+b^2 \geq 2ab$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: inequality

Is $a^2+b^2 \geq 2ab$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$? Is this always true? I tried to find the counterexample for this but I couldn't. But I also don't know how to prove this is true.

Would this kind of proof work? I am thinking I could suppose that $a^2+b^2 <2ab$ and then find the counterexample for this and derive the contradiction.

Comment: Careful... counterexample and contradiction are two very different methods of proof.  Finding a contradiction to $a^2 + b^2 < 2ab$ only proves that $a^2 + b^2 < 2ab$ is false for that specific counterexample you found.  It doesn't follow from one, two, or any number of counterexamples that $a^2 + b^2 < 2ab$ is false for *all* $a, b \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true.

Observe that $$0\leq (a-b)^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab$$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, since a square is always non-negative. Now, rearrange the terms.

Answer (score 1):

It is true because after transposition you get $(a-b)^2 \ge 0$. We know that any real number squared is a non negative  real  number . If the square of a number is negative it would be an imaginary number and it is not the case here as $a$, $b \in \mathbb R$.